# Load data in nested FieldList/FormField in flask forms (WTForm)

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a problem initiating/populating a Form with nested data.

The form is as follow:

```
field_1 --> FieldList(FormField)
    field_1_1 --> StringField
    field_1_2 --> StringField
    field_1_3 --> FieldList(StringField)
```

I want to instanciate the form using `my_form = my_form_class(**data)`.

Here is what `data` looks like:

```py
data = {
    "field_1 ": [
        "field_1_1": "abc",
        "field_1_2": "abc",
        "field_1_3": ["abc", "abc", "abc"]
    ]
}
```

But after after instantiation, `my_form.data` is empty and `my_form.validate()` doesn't pass.

I have other similar forms that are just one level less nested (no `FieldList` inside a `FormField`) and it works fine, could this be the problem?

[This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203059/wtforms-fieldlist-of-formfield-cant-load-nested-data) is having the same problem (no solution). From searching around, I see people talking about multiple CSRF tokens? How does this work?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use:

```py
my_form = my_form_class()
my_form.process(data=form_data_json)
```

instead of:

```py
my_form = my_form_class(**data)
```

Check [this part](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.1/forms.html#wtforms.form.BaseForm.process) of the documentation about the `.process()` method:

> Since BaseForm does not take its data at instantiation, you must call this to provide form data to the enclosed fields.